# Not able to retrieve data field from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to retrieve data fields from my firebase database for the past 5 days without any success. This is what my database looks like:

[image]

Code for fetching data:

```
private void alterTextView(final String id) {
        if(id!=null) {
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                String name = (String) userInformation.getName();


                Log.d("Main Activity",name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mWelcomeUserMessage.setText("Welcome, "+name); 

    }
}`
```

I have no idea why the name is 'null' (refer to log). 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I have defined a blank default constructor, getters, and setters in my UserInformation.java class.

Also, mDatabase is initialized as follows:
`mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

Comment: can you past here the .toString() of your dataSnapshot?

Comment: i dont't understand.. i don't have a .toString() for my dataSnapshot.
i thought getValue() would be sufficient?

Comment: It's going to print a json with key and value.  Log.d(TAG, "Data received: " + dataSnapshot.toString());

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the pictures with the actual code and JSON. You can get the latter by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: the toString() method works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataSnapshot.getValue(Class)` will only load and set values into public fields. I see you already have a default constructor.

Make name field in UserInformation class public. Also make sure the snapshot you are calling getValue on is a valid JSON representation of UserInformation class and has an exact same "name" field (it must exactly match the name field in class).

Please note: 
`addValueEventListener` adds a listener, which will be called when data is available.

Please note that the data is available after `onDataChange` has been called. That's why you should set your text right after you get the data you need from the `DataSnapshot`. Like that:

```
private void alterTextView(final String id) {
            if(id!=null) {
            mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    UserInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                    String name = (String) userInformation.getName();
                    Log.d("Main Activity",name);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            mWelcomeUserMessage.setText("Welcome, "+name); 
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: i did this. now when i try displaying the class using the dataSnapshot.toString() method, there is no issue. But, when i try setting the text of my text view, it's still blank. i use a regular getter method to obtain the name.

Comment: @Yash provide some code please. You may be setting TextView's text in the onDataChange method. You can't do that because it is called asynchronously.

Comment: i've provided the code in my recent update of the question. It still shows null

Comment: @YashChowdhary, I think the code in question is your UserInformation bean class.